# [jQuery]: append a selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to write a reusable function to retrieve all data in a table that is passed to it and store it in an array.

I'm not sure how to pass the reference to the table.

I could do something like...

```
passTableRef($('#tableId th'),$('#tableId td'));
```

but I would like to pass just the table reference in case I would like to elaborate on the function.

Is there a way to pass `$('#tableId')` and append the reference to `$('#tableId th')` and `$('#tableId td')` within the function?

**EDIT**: for clarification

I am wondering if you can take a reference - `$(#tableId)`

pass it to a function - `reusableFunction($('#tableId'))`

then do something like this..

```
function reusableFunction(table)
{
  //change the selector $("#tableId") to $("#tableId th")
}
```

Comment: I'm a little bit confused on what you are trying to accomplish. You want to append the selectors so that when you pass in a table you generate a selector to retrieve the th and td elements for that table?

Comment: Your question still doesn't make sense. What does 'append $("#tableId") to $("#tableId th")' mean? You can't append a table to one of its own cells.

Comment: I want to CHANGE the selector from $('tableId') to $('#tableid th')

Comment: I suppose 'append' is a misnomer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in just the table and just continue down to whatever you want with [`find`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find#expr).

```
someFunc( $('#tableId') );
```

then...

```
function someFunc( table ) {
  var tds = table.find('td');
}
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need the whole jQuery object all over again; $('#foo').add('.bar') works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a reference to the specific table, the identifier should be all you need: `$('#tableId')` refers exactly to the table. If you need to refer to more specific parts later, just take that jQuery object inside your function and look at the `th` or `td` parts with `add("td")` or `add("th")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a jQuery object you can call find() with a selector to find descendant elements. So you could have a function something like this:

```
function findTableElements(table) {
  var th = $(table).find('th');
  var td = $(table).find('td');
}
```

and use it like so:

```
findTableElements($('#tableId'));
```

More info on the find function can be found in the docs http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find#expr